# Javascript and Python - Best communication method

Tags: javascript, php, python, ajax, lamp

I am trying to make a html/javascript controlled raspberry pi robot.

So far, I have installed a LAMP server and I am hosting a local webpage with buttons which trigger events and sends commands to my robot via AJAX. AJAX calls a php script which calls a python script (no CGI) to control the robot.

This solution is currently working for me and I can control my raspberry pi hardware from html and simple send data back and forth.

Now what I want to do is, on my web page, have an on/off button which initializes and shuts down the robot, as well as having other events (currently measuring tilt angles from an accelerometer in an android device) to control the speed of the robot. This is where I am getting confused by the procedure of how things will work.

When I make an AJAX call to start the robot, that ajax call does not close until the python script ends (robot shuts off). So I have a python script running (start.py) which contains my robot object where the methods for changing the speed are stored. If I have seperate events in JS to change the speed (sends a call to changespeed.py), how can I change the properties of an object which is stored in a  different python script (start.py) that is already running (See figure below)?

Possible solutions I have thought of thus far:

1) store the object somewhere in memory. Perhaps as a python object, or store its properties in a SQL database. This way, changespeed.py (or Javascript directly) can change the speed properties in that memory, and start.py can continuously read them.

2) Rather than having the new speed values sent to python through AJAX, let python try to retrieve the values from javascript variables. in other words, instead of javascript giving data to python, have python take the data from javascript (scraping?).

3) abandon my current method of having javascript and python communicate through AJAX and php, and set up a websocket to exchange data. I dont know how this works quite yet but it may be the solution I need.

4) I also have not done any programming with interrupts and I dont know much about it. Is it possible to have my main script running and when the speed needs to change, I can send an interrupt at any moment?

I am sorry if my question is a little vague or wordy. I have a lot going on in my head right now. Let me know if it is unclear. Thank you.

TLDR: what is the best way to have javascript execute python scripts and then feed data to that script asynchronously

[Map of operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUIL7.png)

Comment: Best way I know of is to have JS do whatever it needs to do, and then make POSTs back to the server with django or similar running.

Comment: "how can I change the properties of an object which is stored in a different python script (start.py) that is already running". Off the top of my head, maybe the in-memory program could have a thread which listens for socket connections to it. Your ajax request calls a server-side script on the webserver, which makes a socket connection to the running process and sends data to it. The running process accepts the connection and acts on the data. No idea how you do any of that with Python but that's one theoretical approach.

Comment: I am currently looking into using websockets. based on my research, this seems to be the best method for what I am trying to do. I successfully created a websocket from python to JS, but Apache2 was getting in the way. I am currently looking into if I should use 3rd party software to make apache2 compatable, use nginx, or use a flask framework with socketio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  cgi — Common Gateway Interface  and By the use  cgi-cgi.FieldStorage() you can able to get data in python .it support Huge data transmission and fast.it spport all the browser

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are looking for an in-memory data store such as [Redis](https://redis.io/). With redis you can create a variable in memory which can be accessed by any programming language that has support for Redis (pretty much all of them do).

Redis also has Pub/Sub functionality which allows you to execute specific logic when data is published to a specific channel. For example, if your javascript program changes something in redis, your python program could be subscribed to that specific variable, and know to execute it's own logic when the javascript program changes the value of that variable. For more information on pub/sub check out [this page](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like what I was thinking of doing with a MySQL database. I will look into it over the next day or so and I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully set up a websocket between my webpage and my robot using Flask-socketIO. I am now able to control my robot using the accelerometer in my android phone, but the response from the robot is way too slow. sometimes it takes up to 2 seconds for the robot to respond to a command from my phone. I believe part of the issue is that my robot is connected to my WLAN through a wifi extender in my house. So rather than passing data through the wifi extender, to the router, back through the extender, and finally to the robot, I am planning on using my 2nd wifi antenna as an access point, and connect to the robot directly.

Eventually I plan on getting into android app development (I want to connect my 2nd smartphone to the robot via USB and have access to the accelerometer, magnetometer, GPS, and camera). Once I do, I will look into connecting my phone and robot via bluetooth rather than websocket.

I still dont know if this is the best method, but this is my solution at the moment.